# How to resave all user accounts on a schedule?

Tags: users, batch-operations, queue

I want to re-save all user accounts on my site weekly because I wrote some code in `hook_user_presave()` that I want to update every week.

Specifically, my `hook_user_presave()` code updates the values of some fields like **Total number of comments posted** and **Total number of articles posted**, and it sends an email if the user hasn't logged in for more than a month. (This info is only available to the site admin, which is me, so it doesn't need to be perfectly in sync.)

Right now, I have a View with VBO that I can use to re-save all the user accounts manually. I want to automate this process by saving all the users automatically at 3 am on Sunday.

How do I schedule all user accounts to be saved?  Is this a task for [Queue API](https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-queue-api-powerful-manual-and-cron-queueing/) or does core/contrib provide something more appropriate for this use case?

Comment: [Presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) runs on updates too. So that will skew your totals  unless you want to count edits.

Comment: Why not do the +1 to the user field when a new node or comment is inserted?

Comment: @NoSssweat I anticipate that the average user on the site will perform 25-200 actions per day that result in something counted by my `hook_user_presave()` code (mainly because this includes Flag module flaggings).  The fields that are set by the code are only needed to send the email, which won't happen more than once a week, so I want to minimize load on the server by only saving the user accounts (automatically) once a week or so instead of every time.

Comment: You could write a drush command that leverages the queue api, and then call it once a week and process the queue yourself. I wrote something similar recently.

Comment: Yeah sounds like hook_cron and a QueueWorker plugin. Check this article https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-queue-api-powerful-manual-and-cron-queueing/ but replace hook_entity_insert with hook_cron and in there query all user IDs and add them to the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron)

Provides a UI where you can schedule all the cron jobs. Example:

[image]

---

#### [Job Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/job_scheduler)

Provides an API to schedule jobs.

Simple example:

> ```
> // Declare scheduler.
>
>   function example_cron_job_scheduler_info() {
>     $schedulers = [];
>     $schedulers['example_unpublish'] = [
>       'worker callback' => 'example_unpublish_nodes',
>     ];
>     return $schedulers;
>   }
>
> // Add a job.
>
>   $job = [
>     'name' => 'example_unpublish',
>     'type' => 'story',
>     'id' => 12, // must be unique
>     'crontab' => * 3 * * 0, // Every Sunday at 3 AM
>     'periodic' => TRUE, // set to false if you want to just run once.
>   ];
>   $service = \Drupal::service('job_scheduler.manager');
>   $service->set($job);
>
> // Work off a job.
>
>   function example_update_users_total(\Drupal\job_scheduler\Entity\JobSchedule $job) {
>     // Do stuff.
>   }
> ```

There is more examples & info in the [READ.ME](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/job_scheduler/-/blob/8.x-3.x/README.txt), so read it.

---

**Important**

It's important to note that the above in reality is scheduled to run **the next time someone visits the site after 3am on Sunday**. So if no one visits the site until say 9am on Sunday, it will not run until 9am. This is because Drupal's Cron can only run when Drupal is initialized.

The only way to be sure that it runs at 3am, you have to set a cron job in your server (just know that your server time may not be the same as your timezone, so you'll have to check that), using the `crontab -e` command (for linux) will open the file where you can add jobs to the server. Have this server job run a file that contains code that performs a GET request on your site. OR alternatively a custom Drush command like Kevin commented.